# UITableViewAutomaticDimension and its Height

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in a tableView and its working fine, but when table get loaded, then I need the cell's row size. of the table. Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every cell will be calculated separately, so there is no one cell height.

Comment: Yes, @Marcel you are right. and I need those cell's height.. & Kacper Cz's & pacification's answer is correct. it serves my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ViewController conform to `UITableViewDelegate`, set the table view's `delegate` to the class, then use this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let frame = cell.frame
    [...]
}
```

Comment: or if by _I need the cell's row size. of the table. Is it possible ?_ you mean the whole table height you need to use `tableView.contentSize.height`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by `cell.frame`. If you haven't `cell`, but have `indexPath` of `cell` you can do this way:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
    let size = cell.frame
}
```